# How to resolve this physical collision with impulses?

Tags: algorithm, game-physics, physics

I've started to write a physics engine but became stuck on some physics of resolving collisions. Let's say I have this situation:

[image]

I.e. body B is going towards body A at the speed of 1 space units/time unit. Both A and B have the same mass of 1 unit. Let's consider a completely **elastic collision**.

I've read in a book (*Game Physics Engine Development*) that an **impulse-based** approach can be used to resolve the collision (i.e. find out the linear and angular velocities of both bodies after the collision). As I understand it, it should work like this:

1. When the bodies collide, I get the point of the collision and the collision normal.
2. At the point of the collision I consider **only two points colliding** in the direction of the normal (the points at which the bodies are touching, i.e. I ignore the shapes of both bodies) and I compute the new velocities of these two colliding points (this is easy to do, there is a simple formula found e.g. on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elastic_collision#Equations)).
3. I find an impulse such that when applied to both bodies at this point it achieves the computed velocities for these two points.

Now the problem arises when I consider that from a physical point of view both **momentum** and **kinetic energy** need to be conserved. With these constraints in mind there is seemingly no solution, because:

When B collides with A, B should come to complete stop and transfer all its momentum and kinetic energy to A, according to elastic collision formula. In order for linear momentum to stay conserved, A then has to start linearly moving left at the same speed as B was before the collision (as they have the same mass). So now A has the same kinetic energy as B had, which however means that **A cannot come into rotation** because that would add additional kinetic energy to it (as rotating adds kinetic energy as well as linear motion), breaking the conservation of kinetic energy. Nevertheless, the physically correct solution IS for A to both move linearly to the left AND rotate as B colliding at this location exerts torque (and I've also checked real life object behave this way). Note that we cannot take away some energy of A's linear motion and add it to the rotation as that breaks the conservation of linear momentum.

The only "real" solution is that B doesn't come to complete stop and keeps some momentum while A will be both moving left and rotating. But this doesn't seem to be doable with the impulse-based approach that only takes into account the two colliding points, the elastic collision formula simply say the point at B should come to stop and as B cannot receive any torque (the collision happens in its middle), the only way to fulfill this is for B to stop moving.

So is there something I missed? Is the impulse-based approach just not physically correct? I appreciate any insight and suggestions on how to correctly resolve the collision. Thanks!

Comment: From what I understand, if such a collision happens, then you are correct regarding the conservation of linear momentum and energy. But if say A should rotate after collision (due to it's shape), then shouldn't B also rotate in place now? (earlier angular momentum of the system was zero, so after collision if A is rotating, B should rotate in opposite direction - conservation of angular momentum).

Comment: I think that you would get a better answer to this question if you asked it at https://physics.stackexchange.com instead.  Or possibly at https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/.  (There's nothing wrong with asking here, I just think that there are more folks who would know the answer at these sites).

Comment: You are not at all on the right site.

Comment: Just after collision, there are three unknowns: the speeds of A and B and the angular speed of A. You find these by solving the system formed by conservation of the impulse, of the angular momentum (around the center of inertia) and of the kinetic energy (motion + rotation terms). This system will have a solution.

Comment: I was wondering whether this was the right place to ask and since there exist the physics and game-physics categories I figured I'd give it a go, but I'll proceed to the other sites if no answer emerges, let's just see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The formulas that you're looking at are for the collision of two point masses.  Point masses can't have angular momentum, and so the formulas have no room for that term.

You have to go back to first principles.

Suppose that an edge collides with another body at a point (think corner hitting an edge).  Then a specific impulse is imparted at that point, in a direction normal to the edge.  (Any other direction would have required friction, which would make this a non-elastic collision.)  The opposite impulse is imparted to the other body, along the same vector.  Imparting opposite impulses to both bodies is sufficient to guarantee both conservation of momentum and angular momentum.  But conservation of energy is going to take some work.

Next, what happens when we impart that momentum? As [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/155425/what-is-the-initial-angular-momentum-of-a-rigid-body-given-an-offset-impulsed-fo) physics answer says, we impart momentum as if the impulse happened to the center of mass.  We impart angular momentum equal to the cross product of the impulse and the moment arm (the vector describing how much the impulse misses the center of mass).  This will cause the body to start rotating at a rate of the impulse divided by the [moment of inertia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_of_inertia).

You get kinetic energy from the motion of the center of mass, but also [kinetic energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_of_inertia#Kinetic_energy_2) from its rotation.

So in your 2-D collision you now have the following facts:

1. The mass of each body.
2. The velocities of each body.
3. The moment of inertia of each velocity.
4. The angular velocity of each body.
5. The moment arm of the line of force for each body.

You can now calculate the kinetic energy of the whole system, as a function of the magnitude of the specific impulse.  Unlike the point mass, ALL of these factors play into it, making the equation complicated.  However, like the point mass, you'll get a quadratic equation with 2 solutions.  One solution is 0 impulse imparted (representing the system before the collision), and the other is your answer afterwards.  Complete with changes to the momentum and angular momentum of both systems.

Comment: A lot of this makes sense and is consistent with what I've read -- OK, now I understand that I should solve the system of equations and solve for the magnitude of the impulse. But one thing that comes to my mind now is: how can in my above example angular momentum even ever be conserved? A will rotate and there is no possible way for B to counter rotate (the arm will be 0, or you can even imagine a circle/sphere shape in place of B which cannot ever be made to rotate without friction AFAIK).

Comment: @MiloslavČíž Angular momentum need not look like spin. From the inertial reference of A's original center of mass, even without spin, the object B has angular momentum equal to its mass times velocity cross moment arm. The impulse transfers angular momentum between the two, and just as much is given to A as is taken from B.

Comment: Thank you very much @btilly for these answers.